# When did the Buffy switch take place?

Tags: comics, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In issue #7 of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* Season 9, it's revealed that Buffy is

> a robot.

How long has this been the case?  Is she the same

> Buffybot

as we saw in the TV series?  Were there clues to this (presumed) swap earlier in season 9 (or even 8)?

Comment: Should not looked at the spoilers :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Buffybot in the Season 9 cartoons is constructed from parts that Andrew discovered in Warren's lair. The original Buffybot was destroyed in [Buffy: Bargaining, Part 2](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/102_scri.html) but it appears that Warren had sufficient parts and equipment to build an entire new unit (in fact several, if you don't mind it having more than one left arm).

[image]

[image]

As to when the swap occurred, the implication is that it happened sometime between the end of #03 and the start of #05, when the fact that she couldn't metabolise food started to become noticeable.

We actually see the transfer (which involves a mind-transfer) taking place in flashback in #08.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the comics, but everything I've found in my searches indicates that the Buffybot being used in the comics is a new unit. The original Buffybot was destroyed by a group of demon Bikers when they took over the town in season 6.

Comment: Ah, the OP was asking *when* it happened, not how it happened...

Comment: The OP had three questions. To be fair, I cannot answer two (when it happened and if there any indication), but I am answering the second one: if it is the same Buffybot originally created by Warren Mears.